# Why doesn't ConversationalRetrievalChain refer to anything other than retriever?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am trying `ConversationalRetrievalChain` to create a bot that will roleplay based on what it learns and the chat history.
However, using it, I am unable to get general factual answers.

For example, suppose you had given the bot only a profile of Billie Eilish. Then, let's say you ask her (the bot who is roleplaying her) about her brother, Finneas. I would then want to get a general factual answer that I have not had it learn. (Please imagine asking a question about Finneas on ChatGPT app. It will probably answer it.)

What should I do? You don't necessarily have to use `ConversationalretrievalChain`.

```
def handleMessage(message):
  loader = TextLoader("./learning.txt")
  text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=30, chunk_overlap=10)
  documents = text_splitter.split_documents(loader.load())
  embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

  vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
  llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
  memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, output_key="answer")
  )

  chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm,
    vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    memory=memory,
    return_source_documents=True,
    verbose=True,
  )

  result = chain({"question" : message})
  return result["answer"]
```

I would also like to know how can I give it prompt.